# How do I detect multithread mode in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3.2, thread-safety

Can I detect a multi-thread mode in a Rails application?

I understand that Rails does not care about multi-threading and it is controlled by Rack middleware. But is there some way to to detect it? Maybe using a flag?

I am worried that will happen in the future transition to a multi-threaded server and my code will not work correctly:

```
  prev_zone = Time.zone
  Time.zone = @channel.city_time_zone
  res = Time.zone.parse(str, base_date)
  Time.zone = prev_zone
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there seems to be a way to determine whether your rails app runs multithreaded or not, but it differs slightly between rails 3 and 4.

in rails 4 you can do:

```
YourApp::Application.allow_concurrency?
```

and in rails 3 the way you would to it is:

```
YourApp::Application.config.allow_concurrency
```

note, that you cannot use the rails 3 way of doing it in rails 4. if you're curious why then check out the source code (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L68).

as you found out by yourself, there is a handy method called #use_zone provided by active support:

```
[15] pry(main)> Time.use_zone('Sydney') { Time.zone.parse('01/01/2013 12am') }.utc
=> 2012-12-31 13:00:00 UTC
[16] pry(main)> Time.use_zone('Berlin') { Time.zone.parse('01/01/2013 12am') }.utc
=> 2012-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
[17] pry(main)> Time.use_zone('Alaska') { Time.zone.parse('01/01/2013 12am') }.utc
=> 2013-01-01 09:00:00 UTC
```

It's mostly implemented the way you did it with a minor exception: they use a thread-local variable to store the intermediate time zone to make the code threadsafe: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb#L39

they also use an ensure block to restore the original time zone: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb#L49

so by using active support's Time#use_zone you should be prepared for multithreaded servers.

Comment: Yes, you right! And i forget http://apidock.com/rails/Time/use_zone/class :) But now i know about allow_concurrency, thanks!